# Select case in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

how can I translate this into LINQ?

```
select t.age as AgeRange, count(*) as Users
from (
  select case  
    when age between 0 and 9 then ' 0-25'
    when age between 10 and 14 then '26-40'
    when age between 20 and 49 then '60-100'
    else '50+' end as age
  from user) t
group by t.age
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936028/linq-case-statement , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209924/switch-statement-in-linq , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436028/linq-to-sql-case-query , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936028/linq-case-statement

Comment: In case anyone came across this and wondered "what is the difference between them" Only one is, maybe, duplicate was:  stackoverflow.com/questions/436028/linq-to-sql-case-query and it doesn't specify ranges in the title, however it is the answer. The others are limited to case statements, but within specific scenarios. The answer marked in the actual question has nothing to do with ranges as the question specifies... so....

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
from u in users
let range = (u.Age >= 0  && u.Age < 10 ? "0-25" :
             u.Age >= 10 && u.Age < 15 ? "26-40" :
             u.Age >= 15 && u.Age < 50 ? "60-100" :
            "50+")
group u by range into g
select new { g.Key, Count=g.Count() };
```

Comment: +1 Wow this helped me in so many ways!

Comment: It helps, but I don't think the labels, such as "0-25", correspond to the conditions.

Answer (score 15):

[check this may help you](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/case-statement-equivalent-in-linq/)

```
var query = from grade in sc.StudentGrade
                        join student in sc.Person on grade.Person.PersonID
                                      equals student.PersonID
                        select new
                        {
                            FirstName = student.FirstName,
                            LastName = student.LastName,
                            Grade = grade.Grade.Value >= 4 ? "A" :
                                        grade.Grade.Value >= 3 ? "B" :
                                        grade.Grade.Value >= 2 ? "C" :
                                        grade.Grade.Value != null ? "D" : "-"
                        };
```

Comment: Copy/paste from another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936028/linq-case-statement/936136#936136)

Comment: @abatishchev- changed I thought its good example but no probs answer is updated by another example

Answer (score 6):

Use something like that:

```
class AgeHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<IEnumerable<int>, string> dic = new Dictionary<IEnumerable<int>, string>
    {
        { Enumerable.Range(0, 10), "0-25" },
        { Enumerable.Range(10, 5), "26-40" },
        { Enumerable.Range(15, 35), "60-100" }
    };

    public string this[int age]
    {
        get
        {
            return dic.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.Contains(age)).Value ?? "50+";
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of @Botz3000's answer:

```
from u in users
let range = new AgeHelper()[u.Age]
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
var users = (from u in Users
             select new
             {
                User = u,
                AgeRange =
                    u.Age >= 0 && u.Age <= 9 ? "0-25"  :
                    u.Age <= 14              ? "26-50" :
                    u.Age <= 49              ? "60-100":
                                               "50+"
              }).GroupBy(e => e.AgeRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way how to create efficient SQL like this, using a LINQ statement. But you can use:

1. Use a stored procedure (or function), and call the stored procedure from LINQ.
2. [Use Direct SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx)

Sure you can use a lot of inline conditional statements (`? :`), but I don't think the result will be efficient.